# Get all input of int from cin separated with space in c++

Tags: c++

N = Input How much attempt (First Line). 
s = Input How much value can be added (Second, fourth and sixth lines). 
P = Input of numbers separated with space.

```
Example : 
3 ( Input N )
2 ( s 1 )
2 3
3 ( s 2 )
1 2 3
1 ( s 3 )
12

Example : 
Read #1: 5 (Output s1 = 2 + 3)
Read #2: 6 (Output s2 = 1+2+3)
Read #3: 12 (Output s3 = 12)
```

I've been searching and trying for very long but couldn't figure out such basic as how to cin based on given numbers, with spaces and add all values into a variable. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int l, o[l], r, p[r], i;
    cin >> l;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        cin>>o[l];
        r = o[l]; // for every o[0] to o[l]
    }
    while (cin>>o[l]) { 
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
            cin>>p[o]; // for every o[0] to o[l] 
            // i.e o[l] = 1 then 2 values can be added (because it starts from zero)
            // input 1 2 
            // o[1] = {1, 2}
            int example += o[1];
            cout<< "Read#2: " << example;
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work. Then i found getline(), ignoring the s and just input anything that will finally be added to a number,  turned out it is only usable for char string. I tried scanf, but I'm not sure how it works. So im wondering if it's all about s(values) × 1(column) matrix from a looping but sill not sure how to make it. Any easy solutions to this without additional libraries or something like that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t; //number of attempts
    cin >> t;
    while(t--) { // for t attempts
        int n, s = 0; //number of values and initial sum
        cin >> n;
        while (n--) { //for n values
            int k; //value to be added
            cin >> k;
            s += k; //add k to sum
        }
        cout << s << "\n"; //print the sum and a newline
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to add more details, (i.e. print Read#n on the nth attempt), you can always use

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

to replace while(t--) and at the end of the attempt just print

```
cout << "Read#" << i << ": " << s << "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Does it need an array if want to cout first to last sums at the end of the looping ?

Comment: Thank you again, no need for an array. it matches with the requirement and working as expected now.